# Make certain objects non editable in adobe acrobat (pdf)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat

Is there any way to lock certain objects so they cannot be edited in Adobe Acrobat?

Example:
I made post card in illustrator and i want person who opens it in adobe acrobat only to be able to edit text. (Lock all other objects so they can't be moved or edited)

Is it possible to make pdf with some locked and non-editable objects in **illustrator**?
Or may be there is other software what is cable of doing such think like **InDesign**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Adobe Acrobat put a security password and in file properietes allow only for filling forms (which will be your text boxes).

Comment: PDF apps are free to make up their own mind as to which features they adopt. If someone really wanted to edit data, they could use an app that doesn't respect that security aspect.

Comment: In this case i just wanted restrict editing for some objects so they don't mess up file. I found "Prepare form" option, which should be fine i think.

Comment: There is *no such thing* as a "secure" PDF. All PDF security is **easily** overcome in a number of ways if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can make edits difficult but you cannot prevent them. For ex. one can take enough zoomed screenshots and combine them to get a high resolution image of the wanted parts and continues in Photoshop if he cannot extract images directly in Acrobat.

Using passwords and form structures is one (already said by others) way to create obstacles. Unfortunately cracking software exists, but a part of users surely beware installing such items. Another way is to build your images so that they splinter in bizarre way. Vector images and raster images can be rebuilt in a way that one easy to extract image contains unrelated elements, say 10 parts from one interesting image and other 10 parts of another and third interesting image.

Rasterize vector shapes with no extra resolution beyond the intended usage needs. Let all probably nice to extract parts have some background other than 100% white if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For the computer to be able to draw the data the data need to be present in exactly the same way as when editing data. Therefore if a user can view the document they can also edit the document.

You can always downgrade the data in some way. But this also inevitably reduces the usefulness of the data. There are entire industries who have had to do big changes in how they work because of this computation duality. (this will change a lot of money measured in billions have been sunk into making it possible. Now finally a viable technique is emerging)

In reality you depend on the other party to work with you. So the only thing that really shields you is legal frameworks. Nothing else.